# Сравнение или приложение?

Tags: сравнение

Но, как мудрый руководитель, он всегда думает о будущем своей страны.
Но как мудрый руководитель он всегда думает о будущем своей страны.
В чем отличие первого предложения от второго по смыслу?
В первом он - и есть мудрый руководитель или его сравнивают с мудрым руководителем?
А во втором предложении он - кто?

Answer (score 2):

Смысл один, но выражается разными средствами синтаксиса и пунктуации.

Но, как мудрый руководитель, он всегда думает о будущем своей страны. - приложение со значением причины: Но, так как он является мудрым руководителем, он...

Но как мудрый руководитель он всегда думает о будущем своей страны. - но в качестве мудрого руководителя он всегда думает...  Только чего-то в этой конструкции всё равно не хватает. Я бы  поставила 1 запятую: Но как мудрый руководитель, он всегда думает о будущем своей страны

Answer (score 2):

1. В этой фразе я вижу два момента:
   a) связь между причиной  (руководитель мудр) и следствием (думает о будущем - помимо прочих проявлений мудрости);
   б) противопоставление "мудрости" ранее сказанному - при помощи "но", которое относится к ней, а не к "думам".
   Мне представляется естественным выразить этот смысл ("как человек/руководитель мудрый,") вариантом с одной запятой, которая соответствует и речевой паузе. "(По долгу службы он отвечает только за текущую работу.) Но как мудрый руководитель, он всегда думает о будущем своей страны."
2. Вариант без запятых по форме эквивалентен выражению "Но как руководитель он занят перспективным планированием." При таком варианте пунктуации теряется связь его "мудрости" с его делами и мыслями и "мудрый руководитель" становится просто ипостасью или должностью (ему это положено как принятому на работу "мудрым руководителем"). С протиповоставлением чему (при помощи "но") вяжется такая фраза? Разве что с ошибочным мнением, которому фраза противопоставляется как нечто само собой разумеещееся. "(Можно подумать, что он занимается только текущими проблемами.) Но как мудрый руководитель он всегда думает о будущем своей страны." Такой вариант возможен, но оттенок получается не совсем естественным, как бы поясняют тем, кто недопонимает: "он ведь мудрый руководитель - это обычное занятие мудрых руководителей".
3. Вариант с двумя запятыми. Это можно себе представить разве что в публичной речи с ритуальной паузой после "но", где предметом противопоставления является не "мудрость", а "думы о будущем" (он поступает не так, как перед этим сказано, а иначе), но и известную всем присутствующим мудрость руководителя нужно привести в объяснение (поскольку он мудр). "(Он мог бы распорядиться всю нефть из скажен выкачать.) Но, как мудрый руководитель, он всегда думает о будущем своей страны." Это тоже менее естественно, чем вариант с одной запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, Розенталь в правиле о приложении с союзом "как" указывал не только на то, что обороты с "как" не выделяются запятыми, если "как" в значении "в качестве", но и когда такой оборот характеризует определяемое слово с какой-то одной стороны.(Пример из Розенталя: Публика успела привыкнуть к Чехову как к юмористу) В данном случае такой смыл и содержится в предложении, значит, запятых здесь не надо.

Comment: Но здесь оборот в конце предложения, на него падает фразовое ударение, а там другой случай.